# Check the range of numbers

Tags: c#

Can somebody help me to write this in C# code?

Let's say I have:

```
int x = 7;
int y = 10;
```

Now I want to check that `if(x should be in the range of -3 / +3 == y should be in the range of -3 / +3)` so on both the side I have a range to check. I hope I am clear enough.

Let me put this in other words.

```
if (range(x,3) == range(y,3))
```

In this case it should check all the whether any of the number in `x` range is contained by `y`.

Comment: Why not just do if(Math.Abs(x-y) <= 3)?

Comment: You can use Math.Abs(x-y) <= 3

Comment: Wow guys.. I think I should take some rest ... Could not think such simple logic. Thanks :)

Comment: actually thinking about our solutions wouldn't you use <= 6? If x = 0 and y = 6 then x+3=3 and y-3=3?

Comment: @JarrettRobertson: That is very kind. What I was looking for is `if([5,6,7,8,9] == [8,9,10,11,12])` in this case if any number is matched than my condition is true.

Comment: +/- 3 would be `[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and `[7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Math` library. A simple method would do the trick:

```
if (Math.Abs(x-y)<=3)
```